# Two 'script' tags on stackapps

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stackapps

These posts [1](https://stackapps.com/questions/6353/freehand-circles-drawing-tool), [2](https://stackapps.com/questions/4905/convert-share-links-to-markdown-titleurl), [3](https://stackapps.com/questions/4888/filter-se-questions-by-votes-views-and-rep) in the [`tampermonkey`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/tampermonkey) page is showing with two **[script]** tags.

Originally it has [script] tag along with other tags.

> [image: Two scripts tag]

Comment: Repro'd, Chrome/Win X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the logic for tag display on the mini app view was not accounting for the possibility that a tag the author chose (as can be seen in the post markdown) might also be one of the app type tags (app, script or library) and a duplication could occur.

I have changed that logic - fix with you in the next build.

Comment: It has been fixed in `rev 2016.6.16.3679`